# PDO DB Instance returns null

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, null

I'm working on a task manager a like website and I struggle with my *Database Object (PDO)*

So I have a *Database class (DB)* which has a function `getInstance` *(Singleton)*. This works perfectly fine when I create a user using the function create in the `User` class.

Then I made a `Task` class with the same function create, which also uses the `getInstance` function from the `DB` class. But then I get this error

```
   Call to a member function insert() on a non-object
```

The function insert is a function in the Database class which is used to query to the database and insert the data. I use the function insert in the create function of both classes.

**Task Class**

```
class Task {

    private $id, $task, $message, $date, $active, $finished, $user_id;
    public $_db;

    public function __contstruct() {
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
    }

    public function create($fields = array()) {
        if (!$this->_db->insert('tasks', $fields)) {
            throw new Exception('There was a problem creating an account');
        }
    }

}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made grammatical mistake in `__contstruct`. Change to:

```
    public function __construct(){
```

Of course, constructor of class `Task` not caused => `$_db` is empty.

P.S. Really, insidious mistake :)

Comment: Wauw, I am ashamed!

Thanks any way :D